# React Change Navbar color on specific page using React Helmet?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

So I have a transparent navbar background on my home page, but I need it to change background color when I navigate to my services page to #000.

I figured out how to change the page background with helmet, but I don't understand how I would target the navbar and change the color since I am using a layout component that renders on every page.

```
         const Layout = ({ children }) => {
      return (
        <>
          <Helmet bodyAttributes={{ class: "image-page" }} />
          <Navbar />
          <main>{children}</main>
          <Footer />
        </>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the [`location` from the default's Gatsby's props](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/) to make your checks.

Inside your `<Navbar>` component, you will need to get the `location` via `props` and add a class name to it if it matches your services page. It should look like:

```
const Navbar= ({ location }) => {
  return <div className={`${location.pathname === /services/} ? 'whiteClassName': 'regularClassName'`}>Your navbar content</div>
}
```

In the same way that you destructurate `children` in the `<Layout>` component, you can do exactly the same with `location`. Since it's a default `prop`, it will be available everywhere. Once you have your current location, you only need to add a custom class if it fits a condition to your element and make your CSS magic.

Comment: how would i do it with styled components? I know how to add class name on an event change, but it doesn't make sense for styled components

Comment: `props` such `location` are available exactly in the same way in styled-components. Provide your `<Navbar>` component or add the same logic in your styled component but instead of changing the class name, add your style logic.

Comment: but I already have a ternary on my navbar to change color when I scroll, so I can't add another class to it

Comment: How can we suppose that without the code? Code it's code, of course there's always a solution. For exemple, you can always chain ternaries (not recommend because makes the code less readable) or you can render another `Navbar` component with own styles.